# cada vez que ejecuto esta función, se agrega un nombre al div usuarios. pero también se agrega un elemento undefined como elimino el undefined

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

cada vez que ejecuto esta función, se agrega un nombre al div usuarios. pero también se agrega un elemento undefined como elimino el undefined
my array es users[]

```
    function updateUsers(socket){
    let usuarios = document.querySelector('#usuarios');
    socket.on('updateUsers',function(data){
        let i;
        for( i =0; i <= data.users.length; i++){
            console.log(data.users[i]);
            usuarios.innerHTML += data.users[i];
        }              
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se encuentra en el `for`, lo que pasa es que en tu caso `length` te devuelve un entero mayor a 0, por lo que tu inicio lo pones en 0, hay un elemento que no existirá, puedes solucionarlo quitando el `=` dentro de este.

Por ejemplo, si tu tienes un dato `felipe` `length` te dara 6, y si tu pones de 0 hasta 6 son 7, incluyendo el 0.

Entonces quitando el = quedaría así.

```
function updateUsers(socket){
    let usuarios = document.querySelector('#usuarios');
    socket.on('updateUsers',function(data){
        let i;
        for( i =0; i < data.users.length; i++){
            console.log(data.users[i]);
            usuarios.innerHTML += data.users[i];
        }              
    });
    }
```